# Could not find file specified in Console App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to read a text file and extract text from it. Below is my code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\..\..\Desktop\Logs";

        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

I tried `filePath = @"C:\..\..\Desktop\Logs.txt";` but it shows file

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file error
```

I also tried putting file inside `bin\debug` folder but error remains the same.

Need help If I am missing something.

Comment: is `@"C:\..\..\Desktop\Logs"` your actual path or are you redacting `Users\%username%`?

Comment: I am redacting Users\%username%

Comment: At least mention the `filename` in the `filePath`. How will it know which `file` to read?

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar I tried filePath = @"C:\..\..\Desktop\Logs.txt"

Comment: Modify your code correctly... `string filePath = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Logs.txt;` should work.. of course if your file exists there in desktop

Comment: Try checking to see if the file exists using `File.Exists(path)`, alternatively copy and paste the path into your Windows Explorer and see if it navigates to the file correctly. This will help rule out typos and formatting

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar my file exists on the Desktop and in  your suggestion the quotes are not complete. I also tried putting the file in bin\debug folder and referring only the file from there nut that too did not work

Comment: can you paste the exact code... The `..\..\` will not work if you are using to find the file from desktop

Comment: @DekuDesu File.Exists(path) returns false obviously, but my doubt is if file actually exists on Desktop and the path I got i from the file properties then why Compiler is not able to get the file?

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar here is the code  `static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Logs.txt";

            
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Not found");
            }
        }`

Comment: Paste this in your windows explorer and see if the path opens the file. `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Logs.txt`

Comment: no it does not opens

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar Is there any way so I can add the relative path ? or how can I access it from the default folder?

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar could you tell me how to add a relative path? So I can keep it in some default folder

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)  + "\\Logs.txt" ;
```

OR

Use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` (bin\debug) folder.. Basically where the `exe` is present.

```
string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()  + "\\Logs.txt";
```

Comment: can I include it in Solution and refer from there relatively ? How?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the code:

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\..\", "log.txt");
```

It will look for the file log.txt in the directory of the current solution.